# Can't submit form in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When trying to submit a form I'm getting this error

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

I'm doing it the same way I always have but this time it's not working. I'm not sure if it's because the url is `comments/{id}` I'm not sure if that would affect the ability to save something.

This is the code to submit

```
baseUrl: 'comments',
customUpdateUrl: 'comments/update',
```

If I change those urls to this,

```
baseUrl: 'comments/' + forum.id,
customUpdateUrl: 'comments/' + forum.id + '/update',
```

then I cant see the page, it doesn't load and I get errors like:
If I leave then as is then the page loads without errors

> Error in data(): "ReferenceError: forum is not defined"
>
> ReferenceError: forum is not defined
>
> Property or method "forum" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
>
> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined"
>
> Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined

```
submit() {
this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
        this.loading = true;
        if (!this.form.id) {
            this.$inertia.post(this.baseUrl, {
                comment: this.form.comment,
                forum_id: this.forum.id,
            }).then(
                () => {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: 'Creado correctamente.'
                    });
                    this.loading = false
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                })
        } else {
            this.$inertia.post(this.customUpdateUrl + '/' + this.form.id, {
                comment: this.form.comment,
                forum_id: this.forum.id,
            }).then(
                () => {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: 'Guardado correctamente.'
                    });
                    this.loading = false
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                })
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        this.reset();
    });
},
```

These are the routes

```
Route::get('comments/{id}', 'ReplyController@index');
Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController');
```

Comment: Could you add the router file to your post?

Comment: @sebasaenz I added the routes related to this form

Answer (score 0):

In [resources controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers), the `update` function route uses the PUT method by default.

You should change the POST request for a PUT request for the `update` endpoint (I'm showing you the solution with `axios` because I don't really know how `$inertia` works):

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.put(this.customUpdateUrl + '/' + this.form.id, {
    comment: this.form.comment,
    forum_id: this.forum.id
})
   .then(r => {
      ...
   })
```